# Is Monero the only CryptoNote based coin with a public testnet?

Tags: aeon, testnet

To the best of my knowledge Monero only has two forks, [AEON](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/what-is-the-aeon-currency) and [BipCoin](https://bipcoin.org/)

AEON was forked from Monero prior to the introduction of its testnet function although its lead developer plans to [change that](https://www.reddit.com/r/Aeon/comments/5x5t6m/cant_sync_block_verification_failed_%E8%B7%AF_issue_42_%E8%B7%AF/degdoen/) as part of the [AEON roadmap](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/832/does-aeon-have-a-development-roadmap)

> There is not a testnet because the work that was done to create a testnet function in Monero was after the AEON fork. We'll have one once we switch over to the newer code base.

I can find no mention of a public testnet for Bipcoin.

Are there any Monero forks or other CryptoNote coins with a public testnet or is Monero unique in that regard?

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any other Monero forks besides the two that you mentioned.

There are other [CryptoNote](https://cryptonote.org/coins) currencies but I am not aware of any that have a public testnet. The level of community and developer interest in most other CryptoNote projects is minuscule compared to Monero. Most CryptoNote coins were originally [forked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoNote#/media/File:Forks-tree-fixed.png) from [Bytecoin](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/how-much-of-the-monero-code-has-been-changed-since-the-bytecoin-fork) with development severely lagging behind [Monero](https://www.openhub.net/p/monero). It would surprise me if any of them had a public testnet with much use.